# Bulk inserts with Hibernate 3.5

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch

How can I perform following operation with hibernate 3.5

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
(Value1, Value2), (Value1, Value2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a stateless session. However, be careful because the results returned, customer in this instance, are detached.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

ScrollableResults customers = session.getNamedQuery("GetCustomers")
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
while ( customers.next() ) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
    customer.updateStuff(...);
    session.update(customer);
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Link can give you solution.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/batch.html

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

String hqlInsert = "insert into DelinquentAccount (id, name) select c.id, c.name from Customer c where ...";
int createdEntities = s.createQuery( hqlInsert )
        .executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: I am inserting list of objects by using saveOrUpdateAll of getHibernateTemplate.
and I am getting multiple insert statements.

Is there any other way to insert list of objects using multiple values instead of multiple insert queries in hibernate ?